# Transform 3D Lidar-Points from cartesian coordinate-system to spherical coordinate-system and a stereographic projection

Tags: r, geometry, coordinate-transformation, lidar

I'm working on my master thesis to simulate hemispherical photographs from Lidar-Data. So my main goal is to project 3D Points (X,Y,Z) which are in a cartesian coordinate system to a stereographic projection (See picture 1, from: [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/256548732_Retrieval_of_Effective_Leaf_Area_Index_in_Heterogeneous_Forests_With_Terrestrial_Laser_Scanning)). The coordinate-system of my Pointcloud is transformed so that the center point is located a (0,0,0) and all z-values are positive.

[image]

I'm coding in RStudio and I first tried to achieve a spherical projection of the Pointcloud by using the formula for cartesian to spherical coordinates listed on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_common_coordinate_transformations).

```
r     <- sqrt(x^2 + y^2  + z^2)
theta <- acos(z/r)
phi   <- atan2(y,x)
```

I also tried to do it with the cart2sph-function from the RPackage pracma which should do the same. But unfortunately the results with both methods don't look nearly how I wanted them to be. The points don't fit on a plane half-sphere but just seem to be oriented along the z-axis (See picture 2).

[image]

Has anyone suggestions how to achieve the stereographic projection of the Lidar Pointcloud in RStudio? Is there maybe even a package with some functions to do a coordinate transformation? Unfortunately I don't have many coding experiences, I would be very thankful for every help.

**Edit**

I plot the cartesian points on a hemisphere using Allans script. The result looks like this using the software Cloudcompare:

Image:
[Hemisphere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0B3L.png)

I also did a stereographic projection with the transformed cartesian coordinates:

```
x2 <- (x / (1 + z))
y2 <- (y / (1 + z))
project_2d <- data.frame(x2, y2)
```

Image:
[Stereographic projection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsmpX.png)

Still I wonder why the outer edge of the plots don't fit a perfect circle since all tree trunks have the same min(z) value (I used a clipping box). So all tree trunks should line up on the "equator" of the hemisphere. Do you have any clue?

Comment: Hi Radde. It looks as though your points are all on the y-z plane (though it's difficult to tell with this particular image). Are you sure the transformed variables aren't correct on this plane?

Comment: hey, the points are oriented along the x-z plane and the x zero point splits the point cloud in two halves. But still I can't see any spherical-like transformation in my result.

Comment: If I understand, you project the scene onto a hemisphere, then the latter onto a plane by stereography. What are you showing us on the picture 2 (alias 4) ?

Comment: And why do you mention a spherical projection and show the formulas of conversion to spherical coordinates ?

Comment: Hey Yves, thanks for your answer. I want to project my local points from a carthesian coordinate system on a spherical half plane first and later on a stereographic 2D-Plane (like shown in picture 1). Don't I have to a conversion to spherical coordinates to do so?

Comment: @Radde1683 I think the images look good. Unless the minimum z co-ordinate is 0, the theta value at the base of the trees will vary according to how close the trees are. The further away the tree is, the closer its base will be to the equator. You either need to turn clipping off, or set the minimum z to 0, or clip according to theta rather than z.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to show this result in 3D, but I'll try my best.

Suppose we have a collection of points in the shape of a cross suspended over the camera, paralell to the ground:

```r
x <- c(rep(seq(-10, 10, 1), 2), rep(-1, 21), rep(1, 21))
y <- c(rep(-1, 21), rep(1, 21), rep(seq(-10, 10, 1), 2))
z <- rep(3, 84)
```

We can try to show this in `rgl`, adding a red dot to indicate camera position:

```r
library(rgl)

plot3d(x, y, z, zlim = c(0, 10))
points3d(0, 0, 0, col = "red")
```

[image]

Using the formula you found for transformation to spherical co-ordinates we can convert these 3D points from x, y, z to theta, phi and r. However, to project them onto a hemisphere in cartesian co-ordinates, we need have r at a fixed distance from the camera. We then need to calculate the x, y, z co-ordinates of the points on that hemisphere from the theta, phi, and fixed r. This function should do that:

```r
projection <- function(x, y, z) {
  r     <- sqrt(x^2 + y^2  + z^2)
  theta <- acos(z / r)
  phi   <- atan2(y, x)
  y <- theta * cos(phi)
  x <- theta * sin(phi)
  z <- sqrt((pi / 2)^2 - x^2 - y^2)
  data.frame(x, y, z)
}
```

So now when we do:

```
df <- projection(x, y, z)
```

We can plot again to show the points projected onto a hemisphere:

```
plot3d(df$x, df$y, df$z, zlim = c(0, pi))
```

**View from below**

[image]

**View from side**

[image]

Comment: @Radde1683 see my update for an implementation that should work in rgl

Comment: Hey Allan, thank you so much for your answer! The function worked on my Pointcloud so it projected the points onto a hemisphere. With the formula for stereographic projection I was able to project the hemisphere on a 2D plane:
 X' =x/1+z, Y' =y/1+z (x, y, z)
One more question: Does your function define the radius of the hemisphere? If not, is it possible to define a radius of one for the "spherical" coordinates?

Comment: @Radde1683 yes, the radius was set to pi/2. I have updated the function to make the radius of the hemisphere 1. I would love to see the resulting image you get from your pointcloud if you were able to add that as an addendum to your question. Thanks!